# Why is 'UNICODE' being defined?

Tags: unicode, c++builder, mbcs

I have three [C++Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2BBuilder) 11 Win32 applications that I have inherited. They all use MBCS and not UNICODE. However, in only one of the 3, UNICODE and MBCS is defined in the debug build only. Of course, this is causing compile errors.

I have checked the project conditional defines and UNICODE is not defined. I have searched all project files and cannot find UNICODE defined anywhere. I am new to Embarcadero, so I hope I am missing something obvious that is causing this. does anyone have an idea of where UNICODE may be getting defined?

Comment: It may be in the VCL/RTL source code. Did you try using the IDE's Find in Files functionality? Point it at the EMBT source folders (so it will search both the RTL and VCL source), and search for DEFINE UNICODE. The entire RTL and VCL are both UNICODE since Delphi 2009 was released.

Comment: Also, if you inherited them, why didn't the original developer have this issue? It sounds like either you've  configured something incorrectly, or the previous developer passed on non-working code to you. I'm not sure how they would have disabled UNICODE - as I said, the entire RTL and VCL have used Unicode for more than a decade now.

Comment: I have used find in files and nothing is found. I put test statements in the code to verify if _MBCS and UNICODE were defined. In the release build, only _MBCS is defined while in the debug build, both are defined.

Comment: I believe that the person that I inherited from only converted this project to a newer version of Builder and never tried to build or run it. Changes were made to the other 2 projects at that time, but not this one. I have verified that UNICODE is not defined in the other 2 projects.

Comment: @KenWhite the RTL/VCL is written in Delphi which doesn't care about the `UNICODE` conditional (and consequently the `TCHAR` type), they only affect C++.

Comment: @user22015813 the best way to handle this is to simply write code that doesn't depend on `UNICODE` at all. Don't use the `TCHAR` type and `TCHAR`-related APIs at all. If you have narrow string data, use `char` and `xxxA` APIs directly. If you have wide string data, use `wchar_t` and `xxxW` APIs directly. I know, easily said than done for legacy migrated code, but pretty easy to follow in new code.

Comment: The code does not support UNICODE. This is the issue. I do not want UNICODE defined but it is which is causing compile errors since the code is written for MBCS. Actually in the debug config, both MBCS and UNICODE are defined, but I cannot fine where UNICODE is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the ["_TCHAR maps to"](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/TCHAR_Mapping) option in your project setup *for every build configuration*. `UNICODE` is defined when `TCHAR` maps to the `wchar_t` type (which is the default for *new* projects since 2009, but not for *migrated* projects that were created pre-2009).

> Values of the '_TCHAR maps to' Option:
>
> | value | meaning |
> | --- | --- |
> | `char` | Substitutes `char` for `_TCHAR`. Note: This option does not float to wide definitions of standard library and API functions. |
> | `wchar_t` | - Substitutes `wchar_t` for `_TCHAR`. - **Sets both the `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` macro constants.** - Floats to the wide definitions of standard library and API functions. |

Comment: I have verified this setting. Thank you.